# Ionic Push Notification Custom Sound Not Playing in Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification

I'm having trouble getting Android to play a custom mp3 when I send it a Notification and my app is not running. I'm using Ionic v1 w/ cordovaPushV5.

I know the message is being received correctly and it's being shown in the Notifications area of my physical device.  I just don't get a sound (or any error in the log area.)

I think the problem may be that I don't know exactly where to put the sound file.  It goes in the res/raw folder, I believe.  However, where is that in the Ionic directory structure?

Anything else I should be checking?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out.  It's not immediately obvious, so hopefully this will help someone else.

1. After you generate your Android platform (With **ionic platform add android**), you need to manually create a folder within in called:

**res/raw**

So, the entire path will be:

**/platforms/android/res/raw**

2. Drop your custom notification sound files in there.  Mine was called "sound.mp3"
3. Now, when you send your notification from your server, be sure the message does not include the .mp3 extension.  So, my message looks like this:

   {"count":"2","message":"This is a test","additionalData":{"google.message_id":"0:1490981070460603%bd04720bf9fd7ecd","foreground":true,"coldstart":false},"sound":"sound"}

Note the second "sound" is the filename without the extension.

Pretty easy, but a few little gotcha's.

Comment: while creating res/raw folder, server is not copying raw file, is something missing ?

Comment: raw folder* and file itself

Comment: @SagarPPanchal did you find a solution ?

Comment: @Dicer  did you find a solution?. i am using $cordovapushV5 notification  plugin , i'm having same problem getting Android to play a custom mp3 when I send it a Notification and my app is not running

Comment: custome sound mp3 working properly for app is foreground but background sound not working properly sound play(play defult sound not a custom sound play)